# My GitHub page is not being displayed

Tags: github-pages

I forked a Jekyll theme from https://github.com/Phonations/amavoile.fr

I should then see my site build at this address: https://phonations.github.io/amavoile.fr

Unfortunately I have a 404 error. Is there something wrong in my configuration? Shall I wait a time delay before it is activated?

Comment: Your page appears now, so your issue has obviously resolved itself. What was wrong?

Comment: nothing it's fixed so there is a time delay before activated as suggested. What shall I do with this question?

Comment: or maybe just commiting trigger the page build.

Comment: Write your own answer, and in two days time (required delay), select that as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing commit to the github repository triggered the first build. The page is now available: https://phonations.github.io/amavoile.fr/